# Парсинг JSON GoLang в структуру с динамическим ключем

Tags: json, golang, parse

Есть вот такой JSON файл:

```
{
"exemple.ru:nickname:MOBILE": {
            "id": "ID:nickname:MOBILE",
            "type": "SHOP",
            "meta": {
                "status": "failed",
                "restricted": false,
                "domain": "touchmehome.ru",
                "comments": [],
                "deviceType": "MOBILE"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "category": "123",
                "currency": "123",
                "isbn": "123",
                "name": "123",
                "pictures": "123",
                "price": "123",
                "vendor": "123"
            },
            "cart": {
                "currency": "",
                "multiplyItemsPrice": false,
                "prices": "",
                "quantities": "",
                "titles": "",
                "totalPrices": "",
                "urlTemplate": ""
            },
            "checkout": {
                "placeOrderBtn": "",
                "urlTemplate": ""
            },
            "mainPageTemplates": [],
            "productPageSelector": "",
            "urlTemplate": []
        }
}
```

Есть код в GoLang (select.go):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type All struct {
    AttributesAll       []AttributesAll     `json:"attributes"`
    CartAll             []CartAll           `json:"cart"`
    CheckOutAll         []CheckOutAll       `json:"checkout"`
    ProductPageSelector []string            `json:"productPageSelector"`
    UrlTemplates        []string            `json:"urlTemplates"`
}

type AttributesAll struct {
    Category    string  `json:"category"`
    Currency    string  `json:"currency"`
    Isbn        string  `json:"isbn"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
    Pictures    string  `json:"pictures"`
    Price       string  `json:"price"`
    Vendor      string  `json:"vendor"`
}

type CartAll struct {
    Currency    string  `json:"currency"`
    Prices      string  `json:"prices"`
    Quantities  string  `json:"quantities"`
    Titles      string  `json:"titles"`
    TotalPrices string  `json:"totalPrices"`
    UrlTemplate string  `json:"urlTemplate"`
}

type CheckOutAll struct {
    PlaceOrderBtn string    `json:"placeOrderBtn"`
    UrlTemplate   string    `json:"urlTemplate"`
}

func (AllSelectors *All) getAllSelectors(){
    //var err error
    fileWithSelectors, err := ioutil.ReadFile("selectors.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //fmt.Println(fileWithSelectors)

    var m All
    err = json.Unmarshal(fileWithSelectors, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

app.go

```
package main


var c All

func main() {
    c.getAllSelectors()
}
```

В ответе приходит вот это:

```
&{[] [] [] [] []}
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема

Comment: а динамический ключ - это exemple.ru:nickname:MOBILE ?

Comment: я сразу вижу, что у вас все поля All struct являются массивами, но на самом деле в json они просто структуры. так что лучше убрать `[]` у All struct

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Да, - Динамический ключ - exemple.ru:nickname:MOBILE, Сделал массивами, потому что таких сайтов у меня описано пару тысяч и все находятся в одном json файле)

Comment: Используйте map[string]YourClass для привязки [динамических ключей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412126/golang-parse-a-json-with-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

динамические объекты такого рода можно перебирать как `map[string]interface{}`, но в вашем конкретном случае мы не знаем только первый уровень, а остальное описано, поэтому нам нужно описать `map[string]All`

Но также структура `All` описано неверно. Поля структуры не должны быть массивом.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type All struct {
    AttributesAll       AttributesAll     `json:"attributes"`
    CartAll             CartAll           `json:"cart"`
    CheckOutAll         CheckOutAll       `json:"checkout"`
    ProductPageSelector string            `json:"productPageSelector"`
    UrlTemplates        string            `json:"urlTemplates"`
}

type AttributesAll struct {
    Category    string  `json:"category"`
    Currency    string  `json:"currency"`
    Isbn        string  `json:"isbn"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
    Pictures    string  `json:"pictures"`
    Price       string  `json:"price"`
    Vendor      string  `json:"vendor"`
}

type CartAll struct {
    Currency    string  `json:"currency"`
    Prices      string  `json:"prices"`
    Quantities  string  `json:"quantities"`
    Titles      string  `json:"titles"`
    TotalPrices string  `json:"totalPrices"`
    UrlTemplate string  `json:"urlTemplate"`
}

type CheckOutAll struct {
    PlaceOrderBtn string    `json:"placeOrderBtn"`
    UrlTemplate   string    `json:"urlTemplate"`
}

func (AllSelectors *All) getAllSelectors(){
    //var err error
    fileWithSelectors, err := ioutil.ReadFile("j.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // fmt.Println(string(fileWithSelectors))

    var m map[string]All
    err = json.Unmarshal(fileWithSelectors, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("the full data \n%+v", m))

    for _, all := range m {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("attributes \n%+v", all.AttributesAll))
    }
}

var c All

func main() {
    c.getAllSelectors()
}
```

вывод

```
the full data 
map[exemple.ru:nickname:MOBILE:{AttributesAll:{Category:123 Currency:123 Isbn:123 Name:123 Pictures:123 Price:123 Vendor:123} CartAll:{Currency: Prices: Quantities: Titles: TotalPrices: UrlTemplate:} CheckOutAll:{PlaceOrderBtn: UrlTemplate:} ProductPageSelector: UrlTemplates:}]
attributes 
{Category:123 Currency:123 Isbn:123 Name:123 Pictures:123 Price:123 Vendor:123}
```